# how to hide resubmit alert in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page , on this page I show result of my form . when I want to reload the page it shows : "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier"
and this alert force the users to press resend.
is there a way to hide this alert in firefox like chrome ?
i want to reload the page without any permission?

Comment: Don't use refreshes on pages with forms.  I would expect that behavior on any browser.  If you have forms, I would expect you would use a POST or some other method to communicate the form info.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 but i have to refresh the page after login and i don't want to show this alert

Comment: Is the form the login input?  You should never need to refresh a user's browser.

Comment: @inaz - With no offence intended, what you *want* is immaterial if it's not possible. As TheIncorrigible says, what you're seeing is expected behaviour which you may not be able to suppress (suppression is normally a bad idea, anyway.) Instead, the normal approach is to redirect somewhere after form submit, so if *that* page is refreshed, the submission is already further back in the navigation history.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to hide this alert

You're thinking about the problem from the wrong angle.  You can't *change the browser's behavior*.  But you *can* change your server-side application's behavior.

Presumably you have a sequence of steps like this:

1. Client sends POST request to server.
2. Server processes request.
3. Server responds with a page to display.
4. Client attempts to reload the page.

*Reload* literally means *repeat the last request I made*.  What the browser is telling the user is that the last request was a POST with some information, and repeating it could have unexpected effects.

You would correct this by modifying "Step 3" above.  Consider this more standard sequence:

1. Client sends POST request to server.
2. Server processes request.
3. Server responds with a *redirect*.
4. Client follows the redirect, issuing a new GET request.
5. Server responds with a page to display.
6. Client attempts to reload the page.

In *this* scenario, when the browser repeats the last request, it's a simple GET request to display a page.  There's no harm in that (well, there shouldn't be), so the user would get no warning from their browser.

Basically, long story short, after processing a POST you should redirect the user to a new page instead of displaying a page immediately.